# sed: multiple patterns on the same output line

Tags: shell, sed, grep, sh

I have this file ( `languages.txt` ), obtained with `sed` from other formatted files:

```
language   "Afar"
territory  "Djibouti"
language   "Afar"
territory  "Eritrea"
language   "Afar"
territory  "Eritrea"
language   "Afar"
territory  "Ethiopia"
...
```

I want to get results like "language (territory)" in the same line:

```
Afar (Djbouti)
Afar (Eritrea)
Afar (Ethiopia)
...
```

I'm using this command, but not obtaining desired result:

```
sed -nE 's/^language|territory\s+\"(.+)\"$/\1 \2/p'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the entire file is pairs of "language" and "territory" lines, then

```
sed 's/language \+"\(.\+\)"/\1/; N; s/\nterritory \+"\(.\+\)"/ (\1)/' languages.txt
```

expanded:

```
sed '
    # remove the language and quotes, leaving just the language
    s/language \+"\(.\+\)"/\1/

    # append a newline and read the next line
    N

    # remove the newline, territory and quotes
    s/\nterritory \+"\(.\+\)"/ (\1)/

    # implicitly print
' languages.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Dumber and more fragile version of [*glen jackman*'s `sed` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49990376/6136214), with just one `s` command:

```
sed 'N;s/^.*"\(.*\)".*"\(.*\)"/\1 (\2)/' languages.txt
```

Assumes the file order is strict, so that odd lines are languages, and even lines are locales.  Also assumes the quoting format is monotonously consistent.

Output:

```
Afar (Djibouti)
Afar (Eritrea)
Afar (Eritrea)
Afar (Ethiopia)
```

Answer (score 0):

with `awk` it might be easier...

```
$ awk -F'"' '!(NR%2){print v, "(" $2 ")"} {v=$2}' file

Afar (Djibouti)
Afar (Eritrea)
Afar (Eritrea)
Afar (Ethiopia)
```

set the delimiter to quotes, capture the value and if the line number is even print the values in the format.

If you want to filter duplicates

```
$ awk -F'"' '!(NR%2) && !a[v,$2]++{print v, "(" $2 ")"} {v=$2}' file

Afar (Djibouti)
Afar (Eritrea)
Afar (Ethiopia)
```